# CMake: "fatal error: cstdio: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, cmake, esp-idf

I'm trying to CMake a project. I'm new to using it so I guess it must be very obvious for someone familiar with CMake:
In the main folder where main.c is residing I'm including

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
```

This library is found. Inside the file all_ops_resolver.h is a line:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
```

Inside the micro_mutable_op_resolver.h file is another line:

```
#include <cstdio>
```

Now this triggers an error by CMake:

```
> In file included from
> ../main/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h:19,
>                  from ../main/main.c:16: ../main/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h:18:10: fatal
> error: cstdio: No such file or directory  #include <cstdio>
>                                                    ^~~~~~~~ 
> compilation terminated.`
```

The file stdio.h would be located in:

```
~/.espressif/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-2020r2-8.2.0/xtensa-esp32-elf/xtensa-esp32-elf/include
```

which is outside the project directory. I can't figure out what should go into which CMakeLists.txt to point the compiler to that folder. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <cstdio>
```

is a C++ header and the `micro_mutable_op_resolver.h` header file seems to be from TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers which is a C++ library, so you should probably change your main.c to main.cpp and compile as C++.

Comment: Ok, good comment! Now it errors already in the main.cpp file:
.cpp.obj -c ../main/main.cpp
../main/main.cpp:9:10: fatal error: stdio: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: `<stdio.h>` (C-style) or `<cstdio>` (C++, be aware that it puts everything in `std::` namespace) should work, `<stdio>` is not a thing

Comment: We are making progress  Thank you so much! Changing it to <cstdio> solved it. It also now runs over the previous point in micro_mutable_op_resolver.h so this got solved, too! It seems now I'm missing some files but that is another story. So I will consider it closed.

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <cstdio>
```

is for C++.

You are using C, so you should use

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

instead.

Comment: I read about this - however even if I change to <stdio.h> it would not change the error. Also, this is code by tensorflow from google and the example file would compile perfectly.